# Is full text search possible for BigInt type?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, pattern-matching

I am using the following query, for searching text,

```
   $query = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *," .
                "MATCH (keywords) AGAINST ('". $searchString ."'IN BOOLEAN MODE ) AS rel1, ".
                "MATCH (title) AGAINST ('". $searchString  ." 'IN BOOLEAN MODE ) AS rel2, ".
                "MATCH (description) AGAINST ('". $searchString  ." 'IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS rel3 ".
                "WHERE MATCH (keywords,title,description) AGAINST ('" .$searchString. "' IN BOOLEAN MODE) " .
                "FROM cron_video " .
                "ORDER BY (rel1*1.5)+(rel2*1.25)+(rel3*1) desc, `cron_status` ASC LIMIT $start, $pagesize";
```

But, the below query for searching `id` is giving error, which is of BigInt type.

```
$query = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *," .
            "MATCH (id) AGAINST ('*". $searchString ."*' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) AS rel1," .          
            "FROM cron_video " . 
            "WHERE MATCH (id) AGAINST ('*" .$searchString. "*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS rel2" .
            "ORDER BY (rel1*1.5)+(rel2) desc, `cron_status` ASC LIMIT $start, $pagesize";
```

My doubts:
   1. Is it full-text-search possible for a BigInt type.

About First Query:

1. I am not sure about what value I could give for relevant factor (i.e) 1.5  (rel1*1.5), (rel2*1.25),rel3 etc... Whether this value itself suffice, or how could I determine a optimum relevant factor.
2. Is there any way for optimizing the first query.

Answer (score 2):

[From the documentation:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

```
Full-text indexes can be used only with MyISAM tables, and can be created only for CHAR, VARCHAR, or TEXT columns.
```

Bear in mind that `SELECT * FROM ...` is not performance friendly way to select fields. Rather select only the fields that you require. For instance: `SELECT f1, f2, f3 FROM t1`. It will be much better.

**EDIT**

Sorry, my fault, In Boolean Mode the score is either 0 or 1. So your code is correct.

Comment: My table is still MYISAM. But it has BigInt entry also

Comment: I searched net, and one stack overflow answer posted in this way in select field. k. is there any way to achive the same in `Where` clause

Comment: They do not automatically sort rows in order of decreasing relevance. You can see this from the preceding query result: The row with the highest relevance is the one that contains “MySQL” twice, but it is listed last, not first.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: Yeah you're right sorry my bad. I've updated the answer. @EAGER_STUDENT